# NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 20:Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I m new to ruby.
When i use the .empty? it gives me the error NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 20:Integer, But if i use .nil?/.blank? my test gets passed. 
I m actually trying to do source Minus Target query. 20 is my records in source.

```
def self.diff()
    if targetcheck.empty?
      puts "Target table is empty for #{@tableName}"
    elsif sourcecheck.empty?
      puts "Source table is empty for #{@tableName}"
    else
      # minus_result = Netezzasalesmiqueries.source_target_diff(dataone, datatwo)
      @source_minus_target_result = Generalqueries.source_target_diff(@source,@target)
      @target_minus_source_result = Generalqueries.source_target_diff(@target,@source)

    end
  end
```

```
def self.source_target_diff(data_one, data_two)
        puts "(#{data_one}) minus (#{data_two})"
        # database = $dif_env.teradata.execute("(#{data_one}) minus (#{data_two})")
        # database.as_json
        # database
    end
```

```
def self.reporting()
    @error_token = false
    if @source_minus_target_result.empty?
      puts "Target matches with the Source for #{@tableName}"
    else
      puts "There are #{@source_minus_target_result.size} records that are in the Source but not the Target for #{@tableName}"
      #below is for detailed view of missing records
      # @source_minus_target_result.each{|rec| puts "#{rec}\n"}
      @error_token = true
    end

    if @target_minus_source_result.empty?
      puts "Source matches with the Target for #{@tableName}"
    else
      puts "There are #{@target_minus_source_result.size} records that are in the Target but not the Source for #{@tableName}"
      #below is for detailed view of missing records
      # @target_minus_source_result.each{|rec| puts "#{rec}\n"}
      @error_token = true
    end

    if @error_token
      fail("There were mismatches for #{@tableName}")
    end
  end
```

Stack Trace

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 20:Integer
./features/pages/utility.rb:23:in `diff'
./features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:48:in `/^I have a query to compare Source and Target$/'
./features/scenarios/general_file.feature:20:in `When I have a query to compare Source and Target'
./features/scenarios/general_file.feature:16:in `When I have a query to compare Source and Target'
```

Thanks in Advnace.

Answer (score 2):

empty? is a method for strings. You can try using nil? or zero? for integers.

Comment: rails offers `blank?` as an `Object` method so it will function regardless of the return value